# Error Reading custom configuration file in dropwizard Application

Tags: java, configuration, dropwizard

So we have a normal batching application that we decided to port over to dropwizard. We want to use dropwizard for lot of benefits that it gives us out of the box like HealthCheck, metrics etc.

We might add some REST admin end points later but right now we are just using DropWizard Managed Service to start our application in a separate thread. We created a sample config yml file but it's mostly just a skeleton.

This porting over is just mostly lift and shift and we want to avoid huge refactor in our code. The application is currently tied with two different properties file and we want to keep it that way.

We have figured a way out to deploy our app using a custom deployer that generates these property files "application.properties" and "system.properties"
For some reason the app can't read those files and is throwing NPE. This is a java application. All the jars are under lib directory and the config files are under config directory. It just doesn't seem to resolve those files. I have tried searching the dropwizard docs but didn't find anything useful. 
The code just simply expects the file in a particular directory

```
private static final String APP_PROPERTIES_FILE = "/application.properties";
File file = new File(DataSourceFactory.class.getResource(filename)
            .getFile());
```

The dropwizard version : 1.2.2
And this is how I'm running the app :

```
java -cp "deployed/App/lib/*:deployed/App/config/*"  com.commercehub.app.MainClass server config.yml
```

Any comments are really appreciated!

Comment: Please share the code that is reading those properties files and also the DW version. Thanks.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa Added details in the question

Comment: Thanks @stillLearning. Have you tried without the starting "/" and without "/config/" on the APP_PROPERTIES_FILE? Do you get the NPE on ".getFile()" or new File(...)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my classpath. I didn't need the trailing /* for the config folder.

```
java -cp "deployed/App/lib/*:deployed/App/config"  com.commercehub.app.MainClass server config.yml
```